Firebase: google authentication suddenly not working anymore
Not sure if firebase changed anything or my code has bug now it is exposed.
When debug in the script.js, the call back returned user as null. What could be the cause? This is the code in script.js. It is standard from firebase doc.
window.addEventListener('load', function () {

  // FirebaseUI config.
  var uiConfig = {
    signInSuccessUrl: '/',
    signInOptions: [
      // Comment out any lines corresponding to providers you did not check in
      // the Firebase console.
      firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      //firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      //firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      //firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      //firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      //firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID

    ],
    // Terms of service url.
    tosUrl: '<your-tos-url>'
  };

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    if (user) {
      // User is signed in, so display the "sign out" button and login info.
      //document.getElementById('sign-out').hidden = false;

      console.log(`Signed in as ${user.displayName} (${user.email})`);
      user.getIdToken().then(function (token) {
        // Add the token to the browser's cookies. The server will then be
        // able to verify the token against the API.
        // SECURITY NOTE: As cookies can easily be modified, only put the
        // token (which is verified server-side) in a cookie; do not add other
        // user information.
        document.cookie = "token=" + token;
      });
    } else {
      // User is signed out.
      // Initialize the FirebaseUI Widget using Firebase.
      var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
      // Show the Firebase login button.
      ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
      // Update the login state indicators.


      // Clear the token cookie.
      document.cookie = "token=";
    }
  }, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
    alert('Unable to log in: ' + error)
  });
});```


Did you check https://status.firebase.google.com/? There was a problem with Firebase Authentication posted there yesterday (related to 3rd party cookies iiuc): https://status.firebase.google.com/incidents/HwfPFrLgF6MNTBLx9Fnx, and it seems that following this documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/redirect-best-practices

Thanks! I end up recreate a new project and app in firebase to replace the original firebaseConfig section. It works now. 3rd party cookie issue may come up later. This is a good reference to look at.
